# Getting the Database File from Mysql PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

1. Where can I find the database file of my mysql database? What is its extension file name?
2. Assuming that I found the database file, what file should be  imported into phpmyadmin?
3. Any significant things you'd like to add? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all lets clear that on phpmyadmin you can import only *.sql files (from the tab import) or you can copy and paste sql statements.

But before that (import your database into phpmyadmin) you have to find your existing database!

1. Search to  find *.sql file, is so , you can easily import it into phpmyadmin and get your database live again.
2. if not 1, are you using xampp or mapp? if so, you can find all of your databases stored into  **c:\xampp\mysql\data** , as folders e.g. **c:\xampp\mysql\data\schoolDB** and the tables files of `schoolDB` into that folder.

   A. copy all your data folder into you flash drive and try to install xampp/mampp into another PC/laptop and paste your data folder over your new installed.

If this don't help you, could you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: I found my database folder by using the path you gave me. Inside it, includes files that has my table name and a file extension of **.frm** and **.ibd** and an unknown file **db.opt** How do I import this into PHPmyAdmin? 

Am I supposed to copy the enitre database folder and **just paste it** into another PC/Laptop and I will automatically see it when I start the Apache and MySQL in xampp?

Comment: Just copy into you flash the  folder of your database , that you find into \data\  folder, this means that you have the database safe, dont bother for the other files. find another pc/laptop and install xampp again. After that you just copy your database folder into xampp's data folder. Run apache and mysql from xampp console and your database will be inside phpmyadmin again.that's it. Please if that answers  your problem tick it as correct so as others know.

Comment: Tested. And yes, you've answer the question. :)  Sorry for ticking the check button late. I was testing your suggestion :) Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1):

First you must find the Mysql/data folder. As this may be much different depending on your configuration, you can do this:

1. Throughout your PC, using the right search tool (depending on your OS), find the `my.ini` file (hopefully unique, but if not looke at the update date to select the most recent one).
2. With an editor, open this `my.ini` and find a line looking like `datadir=...`: "..." is the path of your `data` folder.

Then it depends on your database's engine.

If it's `MyISAM` look at `data` folder above, find and copy its subfolder whose name is exactly your database name.

If it's `InnoDB` you have to:

1. Find and copy the subfolder like for `MyISAM`
2. From the `data` folder, find and copy `ibdata1` (no extension)

For furtherly pasting that to another PC, you'll have to find the `data` folder the same way as explained above, then put your subfolder (and file, if `innoDB`) at the right place.

CAUTION: if the receiving PC already contains one or more `innoDB` database(s), your newly pasted database will overwrite the existing one(s)!
In this case, you could first rename the existing `ibdata1` before pasting yours: then don't try working with the "hidden" databases till you suppressed the yours and renamed back.
Note that, here, it becomes an extremely weird and perilous exercise...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the answer but if you are using Xampp in Windows, open Xampp->mysql->data. You should see all the databases created in your phpmyadmin.